# Wildfly domain to standalone

Tags: java, wildfly, wildfly-15

We have a Wildfly domain environment with 1 Wildfly master server and 2 Wildfly slave servers, each slave with 2 application instances.
We want now to transform the domain into a standalone environment so we will remain with 2 Wildfly standalone servers and we will decommission the Wildfly master server.

What will be the best way to approach this task?
Should we install Wildfly from scratch on the old Slaves and configure the standalone XML files or should we use the current installation?

Is there a way to convert/migrate all the parameters set now at the domain level to the standalone files or this is a manual task?

Also, can we run the 2 application instances on each standalone server?

Are the server-groups used in the standalone environment?

Answer (score 0):

There is an operation 'read-config-as-xml'  that should provide the XML of your servers.

Comment: And how this can be used?